# Using definite article in news item headlines

Tags: articles, definite-articles, headline-english

The [CNN headline](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/08/31/uk/queen-elizabeth-prime-minister-balmoral-intl-gbr/index.html) reads:

> *Queen won’t return to London to appoint new British PM, for first time in her reign*

Why the definite article *the* is omitted in "for first time" and "Queen"?
Is it just to keep a title shorter or there is any grammar justification for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it just to keep a title shorter?

Yes.